# $17$ is a quadratic residue for all primes $p$ such that $p \equiv \pm 3 \mod{8}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Trying to prove that $17$ is a quadratic residue for all primes $p$ such that $p \equiv \pm 3 \mod{8}$?

Thanks!

Comment: Try $p = 3$ or $p = 5 \equiv -3 \pmod{8}$.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to show that it is a quadratic residue for ALL p, not for some p

Comment: I think Daniel was pointing out that $17\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, and $2$ is *not* quadratic residue mod $3$. Similarly, $17\equiv 2\pmod{5}$, and $2$ is not a quadratic residue mod $5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel points out the statement is wrong, indeed there are infinitely many  primes in both progressions for which 17 is a quadratic non-residue and infinitely many primes for which it is a quadratic residue. To see why, using quadratic reciprocity, 17 is a quadratic residue mod $p$ if and only if $p$ is a quadratic residue mod 17 that is if $p\equiv, 1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16 \pmod{17}$.

Now look for example the primes in the following arithmetic progressions

- all primes $p=8\cdot 17k+3$: are in the progression $8k+3$ and are $\equiv 3 \pmod{17}$ and so they are quadratic nonresidues mod 17. Likewise all primes $p=8\cdot 17k+19$, are   $\equiv 2 \pmod{17}$ and so are quadratic residues mod 17.
- In the same way primes $p=8\cdot 17k+5$ are quadratic non-residues mod 17 and primes $p=8\cdot 17k+21$, are all quadratic residues mod 17, and they are all in the progression $8k-3$.

Dirichlet theorem impies that there are infinitely many primes in each of this progressions.